# Using a GateWay IP to get all devices IP on a network

Tags: c#, ip-address

I have to get the Router/GateWay IP and then incrementing the last octet everytime to scan all the devices.I get the GateWay IP using a function `NetworkGateway()`.

```
        //gets the GateWay IP
        string gate_ip= NetworkGateway();

        //mechanism to parse ,get the last octet and increment it everytime goes here so that    ping_var = "192.168.0" + "." + i; have a fixed "192.168.0"

            for (int i = 2; i <= 255; i++)
            {
                 //changes i for every unique device
                string ping_var = "192.168.0" + "." + i;
            }




     IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);


  // gives 192.168.0.1 when passed "192.168.0.1 "
  Console.WriteLine("Parsing your input string: " + "\"" + ipAddress + "\"" + " produces this address (shown in its standard notation): "+ address.ToString());


//Returns  the Bytes of IP
     Byte[] bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) 
       {
         Console.Write(bytes[i]);
       }
```

For this purpose I used firstly `IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress)` and then `GetAddressBytes()` but it just returned `xxxxxxxx` which couldn't be used for incrementing.

The `AddOne` method suggested [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483236/ip-address-increment-problem?rq=1) also didn't return it.

Any good idea.

Comment: Where's the relevant code? `IPAddress.Parse` isn't a new method, if it didn't work people would have noticed a decade ago. Also what does `xxx` mean? `GetAddressBytes returns a byte array, not a string.

Comment: Updated the code above

Comment: `GetAddressBytes()` gives `19216801` when passed to it a parameter `192.168.0.1` .What can i do of `19216801` to get the requirement

Comment: As I said, GetAddressBytes returns a byte array. `19216801` isn't a byte array. You still haven't posted the *relevant* code, so helping you is very hard. You can easily change the value of the last byte from 1 to 255 and create a new IPAddress from the array

Comment: Okay i did it and posted as an answer

Comment: You may check the updated Question code now and revive your downvote ..Also,yeah agree `GetAddressBytes` returns a byte array, not a string.

Comment: I didn't downvote, although the code is still not relevant to the actual question. I still think you misunderstood what each class, method does but you never posted the code so ...

Comment: I will try it later and play with it...but for now i got what i needed .Thank YOu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple use of `Split()` and i did it .

```
    string gate_ip= NetworkGateway();
        string[] array = gate_ip.Split('.');

            for (int i = 2; i <= 255; i++)
            {

                string ping_var = array[0] +"."+array[1]+"."+array[2]+ "." + i;
                // do scanning here

            }
```

Comment: You can create an IPAddress from a byte array, there's no need to convert it to a string

Comment: I am getting what i needed .I wanted only the last element to get it incremented and that's possible using Split .